# File I/O python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-io

I am trying to find few strings in a file but the line.find() doesn't return true for any string in the file.Please have a look an suggest something.The search has to be sequential and I need to hold the offset value for every string which is found. and the search for next string should start from that offset.

```
def CheckFile(*argv):
  import os
  Filename = argv[0]
  Search = argv[1]
  Flag = False
  FileFlag = False
  offset1 = 0
  offset2 = 0
  if os.path.exists(Filename) == 0:
    return "File Doesn't exist", 1
  else:
    fh = open(Filename,"r")
    for line in fh:
      if Search in line:
        print "Success"
        print (line)
        Flag = True
        offset1 = fh.tell()
        #offset1 = int(offset1)
        break
      else:
        fh.close()
        return "Could not find String %s"%(Search), 1
        #fh.close()
    if Flag:
      fh = open(Filename,"r")
      print(offset1)
      fh.seek(offset1)
      for line in fh:
        if "TestDir1\TestFile1.txt" in line:
          print "Success"
          print (line)   
          FileFlag = True
          offset2 = fh.tell()
          #offset2 = int(offset2)
          break
        else:
          fh.close()
          return "Couldn't Find File TestDir1\TestFile1.txt", 1
          #fh.close()
    if Flag and FileFlag:
      fh = open(Filename,"r")
      print(offset2)
      fh.seek(offset2)
      for line in fh:
        if "Persistent Handle: True" in line:
          print "Success"
          return "Success -- Found the strings", 0
        else:
          fh.close()
          return "Failur -- Failed to find 'Persistent Handle: True'", 1
```

The Ouput :

```
>>> CheckFile("D:\wireshark.txt","NetBIOS")
('Could not find String NetBIOS', 1)
```

Here is the sample File:

```
>    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
>        [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 104]
>        [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.043579000 seconds]
>        [Bytes in flight: 252]
>NetBIOS Session Service
>    Message Type: Session message (0x00)
>    Length: 248
>SMB2 (Server Message Block Protocol version 2)
>    SMB2 Header
>        Server Component: SMB2
>        Header Length: 64
>        Credit Charge: 1
>        Channel Sequence: 0
        Reserved: 0000
        Command: Create (5)
        Credits requested: 1
        Flags: 0x00000000
```

Comment: What strings are you looking for in which input?

Comment: Also, consider making your code less spaghetti. This would be easier to debug if you split your code up into file I/O (open file, check it it exists, yadda blah) and the searching algorithm (which only takes an iterator over lines, or over line/offset tuples.) That way you could at least localise your error instead of dumping a wall of code on SO.

Comment: I am loking for a string named "NETBIOS" and that exists in the file..should I attach the file too..I am new and still learning!

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off; especially around your loop.

Comment: ohhh! thanks for pointing that out...but that just a copy paste mistake....

Comment: @user2781569: Including sample text would be helpful, both input and output.

Comment: @user2781569: you really need to sort out your indentation, it is impossible to say now when the `return "Could not find String %s"%(Search), 1` would be executed.

Comment: @user2781569 Generally, you should include **relevant** code - i.e. you should do some debugging and otherwise work on localising the source of your error so there's a reasonable amount of code for people to look through. (It also makes it easier for you to verify that your code sample transferred correctly.) You should also include a sample input and the expected and actual result for your output. If possible, using dummy data that serves to clearly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @millimoose I am sorry, I am new to this site stuff and programming..My elder brother was working on this...I am just trying to see if I could do it or not..I will keep in mind what you said..and would check everything before I post..Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong test; use `in` to test for values in a line:

```
if Search in line:
```

`line.find(Search)` will only be true if either the value of `Search` is **not** in the line or if it is in the line at a position other than the start.

`str.find()` returns `-1` if the value is not found, or the integer position otherwise. That means that if `line` **starts** with the value of `Search`, `0` is returned, and `0` tests as false in a boolean context such as `if`:

```
>>> 'hello'.find('hello')
0
>>> if 'hello world'.find('hello'):
...     print 'Found but not found?'
... else:
...     print 'That did not come out the way you thought it would'
... 
That did not come out the way you thought it would
>>> 'hello' in 'hello world'
True
```

Next, for any line in the file your test returns `False`, you then *close* the file:

```
else:
   fh.close()
```

which will terminate the loop early; *most* lines will not match your test, you really don't want to close the file that quickly.

You also *always* execute the line `return "Could not find String %s"%(Search), 1`; you want to test if `Flag` is `False`:

```
if not Flag:
    return "Could not find String %s"%(Search), 1
```

You can restructure the search to use the `else` branch of a `for` loop:

```
with open(Filename,"r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if Search in line:
            print "Success"
            print (line)
            offset1 = fh.tell()
            break
    else:
        return "Could not find String %s"%(Search), 1
```

The `break` prevents the `else` block from running. The `with` block takes care of closing the  file for you, using the file object as a context manager.

Comment: I have tried this too...doesnt work with the above mentioned code

Comment: @user2781569: Are you certain you corrected that in all locations? As it stands now, `line.find()` is *certainly* wrong.

Comment: @user2781569: Note that neither `str.find()` nor `in str` will search case-insensitively; if you are looking for `hello` but the string contains `Hello` then no match will be made either.

Comment: Made the suggested changes...here is what I get
>>> CheckFile("D:\wireshark.txt","NetBIOS")
('Could not find String NetBIOS', 1)

Comment: @user2781569: you can edit your question. Add that info, plus a sample from the file that shows `NetBIOS` *is* present.